# In case of WordNet similarity measures like resnik, lin, leacock, etc what is meaning of path length?

Tags: nlp, wordnet, jaws-wordnet

what exactly is path length and how to compute the same. I am using jaws

Answer (score 0):

WordNet is a graph, or, more precisely, a tree of hyponym/hypernym relations. A path in that tree is a sequence of edges and the length of a path is the number of edges in it. Note that the path between two nodes is comprised of the paths between either element and their lowest common ancestor node.

Comment: Hi Qnan, I did not understand by your sentence "either element and their lowest common ancestor node". Can you give an example

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor for a definition of an LCA. And if you wonder why any path between two nodes would pass through their LCA, consider the fact that a taxonomy is a tree and therefore there exists only one *simple* path between two nodes. I think it's obvious why LCA will be on that path, right?

Comment: Hi Qnan, can you tell me how to get word cooccurence value

Comment: Well, yes. You have to count the number of times the words co-occur in a large body of text.

Comment: can you tell me some applications of having the word cooccurence data (as in where can i apply this data?)